# Is there a Python function that shows the progress of a dendrogram after each step of hierarchical clustering?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, visualization, dendrogram

I have implemented an agglomerative hierarchical clustering algorithm in Python for a class I'm about to teach and I wanted to show the dendrogram progress after each step to show what's going on in each iteration when getting the new clusters and distance matrix.
Unfortunately I was not able to find something off the shelf to do that.
If there is no such package out there, do you guys have a hint about the best way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat555/node/86/ and http://www.analytictech.com/networks/hiclus.htm